# LSTM Autoencoder for music - Keras [Sequence to sequence]

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network, autoencoder

So, I'm trying to learn fixed vector representations for segments of about 200 songs (~ 3-5 minutes per song) and wanted to use an LSTM-based Sequence-to-sequence Autoencoder for it.

I'm preprocessing the audio (using librosa) as follows:

1. I'm first just getting a raw audio signal time series of shape around (1500000,) - (2500000,) per song.
2. I'm then slicing each raw time series into segments and getting a lower-level mel spectrogram matrix of shape (512, 3000) - (512, 6000) per song. Each of these (512,) vectors can be referred to as 'mini-songs' as they represent parts of the song.
3. I vertically stack all these mini-songs of all the songs together to create the training data (let's call this **X**). X turns out to be (512, 600000) in size, where the first dimension (512) is the window size and the second dimension (600000) is the total number of 'mini-songs' in the dataset.
4. Which is to say, there are about 600000 mini-songs in X - each column in X represents a mini-song of length (512,).
5. Each of these (512,) mini-song vectors should be encoded into a (50,) vector per mini-song i.e. we will have 600000 (50,) vectors at the end of the process.
6. In more standard terminology, I have 600000 training samples each of length 512. [Think of this as being similar to an image dataset - 600000 images, each of length 784, where the images are of resolution 32x32. Except in my case I want to treat the 512-length samples as sequences that have temporal properties.]

I read the example [here](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) and was looking to extend that for my use case. I was wondering what the `timesteps` and `input_dim` parameters to the `Input` layer should be set to.

I'm setting `timesteps = X.shape[0]` (i.e. 512 in this case) and `input_dim = X.shape[1]` (i.e 600000). Is this the correct way to go about it?

**Edit:** Added clarifications above.

Comment: I think timesteps should be set to the length that is a reasonable span for temporal relationship capturing. input_dim, on the other hand, should be set to the number of variables in a sequence (set to 1 if the audio sequence is 1-D over time). Any progress on your problem? share the code would be more helpful in clarifying the problem:)

Answer (score 0):

Your input is actually a 1D sequence not a 2D image.
The input tensor will be (600000, 512, 1) and you need to set the input_dim to 1 and the timesteps to 512. 
The shape input does not take the first dimension of the tensor (i.e. 600000 in your case).